# Does this formula defines a definable subset?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, logic

I am studying definable subsets in *Introduction to O-minimal geometry, M. Coste*, and I have recently seen some formulas named: *first order formulas*:  if $\phi$ is a first order formula, the set $ \{ x \in R^n : \phi(x) \}$ is definable in $R^n$, where $R$ is a real closed field. I have the following doubt. We know that if $A$ is definable, then $x \in A$ is a first order formula. But, what happens in the situation when $(x,y)$ is a tuple, $A_y$ is a definable subset for every $y$, and we have the subset:

$$ \{ (x,y) \in R^2 : x  \in A_y \}.$$

Is this subset definable? Or, analogously, is $\phi (x,y) \equiv x \in A_y$ a first-order formula? I know the union in $y_0 \in R$ of $\{ (x,y) \in R \times \{ y_0 \} : x \in A_{y_0} \}$ need not be definable, since the arbitrary union of definable need not be definable too, but I do not know how to even begin to prove my question... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the set $X :=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x  \in A_y \}$ won't be definable unless the $A_y$ are defined **uniformly**.

e.g consider the following (non-uniform) family :
$$A_y = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} \{ 1 \} & \textrm{if } \lfloor y \rfloor \textrm{ is even} \\ \{ -1 \} & \textrm{if } \lfloor y \rfloor \textrm{ is odd}. \end{array} \right.$$

Clearly, every $A_y$ is definable, but $X$ isn't definable for if it were, then the set
$\{ y \in \mathbb{R} \ \big| \lfloor y \rfloor \textrm{ is even}\}$ would be definable, a contradiction to O-minimality since .this later set can't be written as a finite union of intervals.

**uniform family** the family $(A_y)$ is uniformly definable if there exist a formula $\varphi(x, y)$ such that for all $y$, $A_y = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \ \big| \ \models \varphi(x, y) \}$, i.e $x\in A_y \equiv \varphi(x, y)$.

Comment: Nice counterexample, many thanks! :) I am a bit confused about what you mean in the end by an uniform family (I think it is because of the symbol "|=").  In the case I am working with I have $A_y = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : \varphi(x,y) \}$ . My only problem is that the formula $\varphi$ depends on the same $y$ on which the $A_y$ depends. But, this is an uniform family according to your definition right?

Comment: @BluePen "$\models \varphi(x, y)$" means "$\varphi(x, y)$ holds". So basically it is just a more formal way to write $A_y = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : \varphi(x,y) \}$. So uniform means that you have a single formula $\varphi$ describing all the $A_y$, with only the parameter $y$ changing.

Comment: OK I understand now, thank you for clarifying this :)